# Combinatorics: How should we count lists?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A manager needs to select a 10-members-committee. The manager wants at least 2 engineers, 3 physicists, and 4 mathematicians. The company has 5 engineers, 7 physicists, and 9 mathematicians. How many possible committees are?

The problem gives a tip to break the problem in cases, selecting first the eight member.

If the tenth member is a engineer, there are C(4,2) ways to pick the two engineers, C(7,3) physicists, and C(9,4) mathematicians. 
Subtotal= C(4,2) C(7,3) C(9,4)* 5 = 132300 (3+4+5 are the people not used in their first selection)

If the tenth member is a physicist, 
Subtotal= C(5,2) C(6,3) C(9,4)* 7 = 176400

If the tenth member is a mathematician, 
Subtotal= C(5,2) C(7,3) C(8,4)* 9 = 220500

Total = 132300 + 176400 + 220500 = 529200

However, I found that a faster method to do the same calculation is

C(5,2) C(7,3) C(9,4) C(3+4+5, 1) = 529200.

***Here is my question:***

***Can we use this short-cut always? Are there exceptions?***

***Is my solution correct?***

I was thinking that to break in cases would be complicated if instead 10 members we need 12 members because the three extra members could be one engineer, one mathematician, and one physicist. Or could be three mathematicians, or any other combination.

***Is is it mistake to go by cases for this possible complications?***

***What would be the solution for 12 members?***

Comment: If we were to first correct your problem that you are looking for $10$ person committees instead of $8$, your solution would still unfortunately not be correct as it distinguishes the tenth member from the other members unnecessarily.  If the tenth member is a physicist he should have been picked simultaneously with the other physicists and you should have had $\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{\color{red}{4}}\binom{9}{4}$ for example for that subcase.

Comment: Isn't $2+3+4>8$?

Comment: @lulu I am so sorry. I just changed my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.  But with $9$ slots specified, we only need assign the tenth so there are only three cases to consider.

Comment: You still refer to the eight member

Comment: @Paparazzi Thank you! I just changed. I am so sorry.

Comment: As to the question of "*can we use this shortcut always*" to that I would say: counting questions can have many different methods and approaches.  Common approaches to elementary problems like this involve multiplication principle and addition principle.  Any approach, if done correctly, will work.  Some times it is more efficient to phrase things in a specific way but there is no golden rule that you can follow that will always make things more efficient.

Comment: @JMoravitz Excellent comment. What would be the solution for 12 members?

Comment: @ Beginner it would be tedious.  @mdave16 no it would not.  That falls into the same trouble as his original solution and is just as incorrect.  We cannot somehow distinguish the people picked at the end as being somehow different than those picked earlier on in the process.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you so much for your help. I do not understand why Using C(3+4+5,3) would distinguish the people. Can you explain me more about it?

Comment: @JMoravitz, yeah, you're right, i just read the earlier comments, i'd overlooked

Comment: Consider this... let us give the people picked in the first steps smiley face stickers and not give any stickers to the people picked at the end in the last step.  Your solution then counts the number of ways we can pick twelve people where specifically two engineers get stickers, three physicists get stickers, etc...  It in particular counts the scenario where we have engineer A and engineer B with stickers and engineer C without a sticker on the team as a different outcome than having engineer B and engineer C  with stickers with engineer A without a sticker on the team (*and enough others*)

Comment: These teams however have the same people on it.  The only difference is who has the smiley face stickers.  Since the smiley face stickers do not actually affect what the team looks like to us, we consider these to be the same outcome but we accidentally counted it more than once.  To properly apply multiplication principle, we can not have any outcome corresponding to multiple different sequences of choices.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that now I am understanding would be like to change from the 3 variables to 4 variables? Correct?

Comment: If you still aren't convinced, then try counting the number of committees of size three we can make from a pool of three mathematicians where we must have at least two mathematicians on the committee.  Using your logic, it would have been $\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{1}{1}=3$ instead of one.

Comment: @JMoravitz I believe you. Your reasoning is powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force solution is to list the $3$ possibilities $(e,p,m) =(3,3,4),(2,4,4),(2,3,5)$ then calculate
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{5}{3} \binom{7}{3} \binom{9}{4} +\binom{5}{2} \binom{7}{4} \binom{9}{4} + \binom{5}{2} \binom{7}{3} \binom{9}{5}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now observe that $ \binom{5}{3}= \binom{5}{2}=10$ , $\binom{7}{3} =\binom{7}{4}=35$ and $\binom{9}{4}=\binom{9}{5}=126$ (all three terms give the same value) so the anser is $ 3 \times 10 \times 35 \times 126= \color{blue}{132300}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! What if 12 members are needed?

Comment: For $12$ members on the committee there are $10$ possibilities, so it will be a bit of work, but you will still be able to get to an answer.

Comment: Then for 12 members, would be necessary to break in cases?

Comment: I cannot think of a method to avoid writing down the $10$ possibilities ( one may well exist) but it might prove quicker and easier to just grind through the $10$ possibilities.

Comment: "necessary" might not be the appropriate word to use here, but it is certainly one of the more easy to understand and implement approaches.  You could also approach using inclusion-exclusion, but I expect you'll find that to be almost as time-consuming and computation heavy.

Comment: @JMoravitz Amazing comment. Inclusion-Exclusion principle. I appreciate also the idea that cases would be easier.

Comment: @JMoravitz With $ m_a<n_a,m_b<n_b, m_c<n_a$. How many ways can we choose a committee of $m_a+m_b+m_c +j$ people with at least $m_a$ of type $a$ out a total of $n_a $ of type $a$ ... etc ... Find a closed form ? ... I need to think about this ... might be easier to just have two flavours of people. But certainly , what is the best way to approach this type of question ? ... Food for though ... $\ddot \smile$