# How many distinct groups?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I had a question about how to finish a particular question:

You're setting up a new company, and need 5 partners chosen from a group of business graduates. Within the group there are 8 Accountants, 5 Advertisers, and 4 Human Resource Managers.

a) *How many groups of 5 partners can be chosen if you need 2 Accountants, 2 Advertisers, and 1 HR Manager?*

b) *How many groups of 5 partners are made up of people with the same occupation?*

**My work so far:**

So it seems to me that for a), I'm to do $8\choose2$ + $5\choose2$ + $4\choose1$ = 28 + 10 + 4 = 42. Although this seems correct to me, there could be some issue with the addition that I'm not considering?

For b) I have less of an idea. Initially, I'm thinking something like taking the total number of combinations for a group of 5, $17\choose5$, then subtracting $8\choose5$ and $5\choose5$, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help, it would be very much obliged.

Comment: You have to multiply, not add.

Comment: To add to lulus hint, consider the concrete calculable examples to test your ideas on, and write down where you have over/undercounted. Try the same problem with a team of 3 with one from each job, if there are 1 person with each jon to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457950/combinatorics-how-should-we-count-lists

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but definitely similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) states that if one task can be performed in $m$ ways and another task can be performed independently of the first in $n$ ways, then there are $mn$ ways of performing both tasks.

The [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) states that if two tasks are mutually exclusive and there are $m$ ways of performing one task and $n$ ways of performing the other task, then one of the tasks can be performed in $m + n$ ways.

With that in mind, let's look at the problems you posed.

> You're setting up a new company and need five partners chosen from a group of business graduates.  Within the group are eight accountants, five advertisers, and four human resource managers.  How many groups of five partners can be chosen if you need two accountants, two advertisers, and one human resource manager.

You are correct that there are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to select two of the eight accountants, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select two of the five advertisers, and $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to select one of the four human resource managers.  Since it is possible to perform these tasks simultaneously, the number of ways we can choose two accountants, two advertisers, and one human resource manager is 
$$\binom{8}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$

> How many groups of five partners are made up with the same occupation.

We must either choose five of the eight accountants, or five of the five advertisers, or five of the four human resource managers (the last task may be somewhat difficult).

> $$\binom{8}{5} + \binom{5}{5} + \binom{4}{5}$$  The last term is equal to zero since $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ when $n < k$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info, simultaneous and mutually exclusive tasks make much more sense now.